# PHP - Add periodic event in api Calendar for the specific day of the week

Tags: php, api, events, calendar

I do not know how I can add a recurring event in the Google Calendar API for a specific day of the week, for example, repeat an event every Monday for the rest of the year or at least for X weeks.

I can make recurrents events with this code:

```
$ Cal = new Google_Service_Calendar ($ client);``
$ Client-> setAccessToken ($ token);

$ Event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event (
    array (
        'Id' => $ event_id,
        'Summary' => $ summary,
        'Description' => $ description,
        'Start' => array (
        'DateTime' => $ startdate.'T '. $ Starttime. ': 00-05: 00'
        'TimeZone' => 'America / Bogotá',
    ),
    'End' => array (
        'DateTime' => $ enddate.'T '. $ Endtime. ': 00-05: 00',
        'TimeZone' => 'America / Bogotá',
    ),
    'Reminders' => matrix (
        'UseDefault' => FALSE,
        'Overrides' => array (
            Array ('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 24 * 60),
            Array ('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 10),
        ),
    ),
));

$ CalendarId = $ id_calendar;
$ Event = $ cal-> events-> insert ($ calendarId, $ event);
```

Can someone tell me if I can add an attribute to add an event every Monday, Thursday or X day of the week? or Whether I need to do it of other way.